# JavaFX WebView resize issue

Tags: java, javafx, webview

How do I resize a web view correctly?  The moment the window gets reduced to a smaller size it seems to push the WebView to the end of the frame, without actually resizing. How would I do this correctly allowing the window to be resized and the WebView to fit in the frame appropriately.

```
public class OuroborosViewer extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Ouroboros");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 1920, 1080);
    scene.setFill(Color.OLDLACE);

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    Menu menuFile = new Menu("File");
    Menu menuEdit = new Menu("Edit");
    Menu menuView = new Menu("View");

    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile, menuEdit, menuView);
    ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(menuBar);

    BorderPane borderPane = createTab(scene);
    ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(borderPane);

    scene.widthProperty().addListener(new WidthListener());
    scene.heightProperty().addListener(new HeightListener());
    //  stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Ouroboros.svg"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    try {
        sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OuroborosViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    stage.show();
}

private BorderPane createTab(Scene scene) {
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.setText("Google");
    //VBox hbox = new VBox(new BrowserToolbar(scene), new OuroborosBrowser(scene));
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    BrowserToolbar toolbar = new BrowserToolbar(scene);
    OuroborosBrowser ob = new OuroborosBrowser(scene);
    VBox.setVgrow(toolbar, Priority.ALWAYS);
    VBox.setVgrow(ob, Priority.ALWAYS);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(toolbar, ob);
    vbox.autosize();

    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    tab.setContent(vbox);
    borderPane.setTop(tabPane);
    return borderPane;
}

private static class WidthListener implements ChangeListener<Number> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
        OuroborosBrowser.browsers[0].setPrefWidth(newSceneWidth.doubleValue());
        BrowserToolbar.URLBars[0].setPrefWidth(newSceneWidth.doubleValue() - 115);
        BrowserToolbar.toolBars[0].setPrefWidth(newSceneWidth.doubleValue());
    }
}

private static class HeightListener implements ChangeListener<Number> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {
        if (oldSceneHeight != newSceneHeight) {
            try {
                OuroborosBrowser.browsers[0].setPrefHeight(newSceneHeight.doubleValue()
                        + OuroborosBrowser.browsers[0].getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable()
                                .get(0).prefHeight(0));
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class OuroborosBrowser extends Region {
public static int browserCounter = 0;
public static WebView[] browsers = new WebView[25];
private static WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();


public OuroborosBrowser(Scene scene) { 
    browser.setPrefSize(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
    webEngine.load("http://www.google.com/index.html");
    getChildren().add(browser);
    browsers[browserCounter] = browser;
    browserCounter++;
}
}



public class BrowserToolbar extends Region {

public static TextField[] URLBars = new TextField[25];
public static ToolBar[] toolBars = new ToolBar[25];
public static int barCounter = 0;

public BrowserToolbar(Scene scene) {
    Button backButton = new Button("  <  ");
    Button forwardButton = new Button("  >  ");
    TextField URLbar = new TextField();
    URLbar.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth() - 115);
    URLBars[barCounter] = URLbar;
    URLbar.setPrefWidth(2000);
    final ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(
            backButton, forwardButton, URLbar);
    toolbar.setPrefWidth(2000);
    toolBars[barCounter] = toolbar;
    barCounter++;

    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.getChildren().add(toolbar);
    hb.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth());
    hb.autosize();
    getChildren().add(hb);
}
}
```

The area shaded in the image below is the area that keeps increasing as the frame height is reduced.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKiw9.png)

Comment: Hello, if you are saying that after compiling it displays shorter size window even if you have given pane size larger initially.then dont worry when you export it into executable jar file then automatically your window will be of the size that of pane say for eg. Anchorpane size in fxml.you can increase size of pane using scene builder too :)

Comment: You are not using layouts properly.  Get rid of all uses of HBox and VBox, get rid of WidthListener and HeightListener, get rid of all calls to setPrefWidth, do not pass your Scene to other classes, and use BorderPanes to make your controls stretch to fill spaces.